# Angular 2: Compare 2 forms

Tags: forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I want to compare if the two values of forms are the same. I have this

```
if(this.holdForm.value != this.positionForm.value){
    this.enableButton = true;
}else{
    this.enableButton = false;
}
```

but it doesn't work. It won't make enableButton true.

> UPDATED:

```
    this.positionForm = this.fb.group({
            'name' : [position.name, Validators.required],
            'remark': position.remark
        });

    this.holdForm = this.fb.group({
        'name' : position.name,
        'remark': position.remark
    });



    this.positionForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
        this.onValueChanged(data);
        if(this.data.process == 'register'){
            this.enableButton = true;
        }else if(this.data.process == 'update' && this.holdForm.value != this.positionForm.value){
            this.enableButton = true;
        }else{
            this.enableButton = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats the error you get ? can you post the two forms

Comment: I don't have error. The other one is a temporary form for previous values. I want to compare if there are changes. See updated @RahulSingh

Comment: you can use library like lodash and its equal method to compare two objects
!_.isEqual(this.holdForm.value,this.positionForm.value)

Comment: This is basically a JS question, so here are some ideas too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects I would go with lodash tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you should do is to write a custom validator, for example the one checking if password matches confirm password field. like:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    password: [''],
    confirmPassword: [''],
    }, {
    validator: matchingFieldsValidation("password", "confirmPassword")
})

export function matchingFieldsValidation(firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        const firstControl= control.get(firstControlName);
        const secondControl= control.get(secondControlName);
        if (!firstControl|| !secondControl) return null;
        return firstControl.value == secondControl.value ? null : {matchingFields: true}
    }
}
```

Then you can enable/disable button depending on the validation status. IMHO the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare the object values directly:

```
var person1 = {name:"John"};
var person2 = {name:"John"};
console.log(person1===person2) // will give you false
```

That is because the both `person1` and `person2` pointing to two *different* references in the memory.

If you just want to compare the values of the two objects, you can have a straightforward but expensive way: stringify them and then compare the strings:

```
JSON.stringify(person1) === JSON.stringify(person2) //this gives you true
```

There are a lot of limitations using the stringified method above. One of them is the order of the properties in the object matters. You might want to think of a more generic solution to compare the object.